# Xamarin.Forms fire wrong tap event in Grid children

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have several objects in `Grid` with `TapGestureRecognizer` but whenever I tap any of generated item, it always fires the latest one added event. But when I use `StackLayout` instead of `Grid` firing events works fine, but the formatting is mess..  So I would like to use grid, but need to figure out some workaround. `AbsoluteLayout` do the same as `Grid`

Code in main `ContentPage`

```
 private void Draw()
    {
        var hexagons = new List<Hexagon>();
        int x = 6, y = 40, id = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                var hex = new Hexagon(id, x, y, 40);
                void Tapped()
                {
                    hex.SetHexaState(HexagonState.Tapped);
                }

                hex.Shape.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer() { Command = new Command(Tapped) });

                hexagons.Add(hex);
                y += 40;
                id++;
            }

            x += 34;
            y = i % 2 == 0 ? 20 : 40;
        }

        
        var grid = new Grid()
        {
        };

        hexagons.ForEach(rec => {
            grid.Children.Add(rec.Shape);
        });

        this.Content = grid;
    }
```

Created [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14677) already on Xamarin.Forms GitHub.

Comment: I know it's not the response you like, but as you have a collection of items that you want to display, I would recommend using a View to do that, like a [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) or [listview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)

Comment: Won't fit my case, cause I have hexagons (honeycomb layout) and these views doesn't allow me to draw it as I want..

Comment: I don't know if it will work. But maybe try `void Tapped(Hexagon myHex)
                {
                    myHex.SetHexaState(HexagonState.Tapped);
                }`. And then change the Command to be something like `new TapGestureRecognizer() { Command<Hexagon> = new Command(Tapped), CommandParameter=this });`.

Comment: There's no problem with adding the event, but when it is in grid or absolute layout it just fires the latest element event, so I can tap any of printed, but the only latest one fires it. So when I use ur approach I get hexagon, but that obtained item's position is position of the last one added. And it drives me mad...

Comment: Just in case, you should move the Command and the Tapped() definition outside  the Draw() method

Comment: It used to be...  Problem is not in draw method.. it is in layout... Grid just mess smth up. As I said.. in stack layout there's no problem with events

Comment: Sorry that i insist on this line, and what about `new TapGestureRecognizer() { Command = new Command(()=>hex.SetHexaState(HexagonState.Tapped)) })` ?

Comment: I've tried that too.. the result is exactly the same. As I said.. when I add those hexagons to stacklayout, problem with events disappear.. but I can't format shapes to wanted format

Comment: I can think of several other workarounds, but I don't know if they will work. Like using a command that passes the ID to a function and that function searches for the ID inside the hexagons list and then change the status

Comment: Yup.. Maybe I'll have to do it as you say, but... BUT ... I just don't want to.. we'll see what Xamarin devs will tell us on this issue... you can add watch on it https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14677 if you want to be updated

Comment: I will check it! Maybe it doesn't fit your needs, but Xamarin Community Toolkit has a HexLayout (I've never used it though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Grid without columns and rows defined will display its children in the same position, so your Hexagons may be overlapping and triggering the wrong TapGestureRecognizer. If your Hexagon class is doing some other positioning logic, it's not obvious as you've not included it.

For a customized layout, consider using an [AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout) where you can set the absolute/relative positions of children within it.

Answer (score 0):

So as Andrew H said, the solution is to use absolute layout like:

```
 private void Draw()
    {
        var hexagons = new List<Hexagon>();
        var absoluteLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
        int x = 6, y = 40, id = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                var hex = new Hexagon(id, 0, 0, 40);
                void Tapped()
                {
                    hex.SetHexaState(HexagonState.Tapped);
                }

                hex.Shape.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer() { Command = new Command(Tapped) });

                hexagons.Add(hex);

                absoluteLayout.Children.Add(hex.Shape, new Point(x,y));

                y += 40;
                id++;
            }

            x += 34;
            y = i % 2 == 0 ? 20 : 40;
        }

        Content = absoluteLayout;
    }
```